# PHP and jQuery dialog interaction for submitting form

Tags: php, jquery, dialog, modal-dialog

I need a help with PHP and jQuery interaction, at the moment I'm weak in interaction with PHP and jQuery so I don't understand some things.. Ok the thing is that I have form with PHP generated table. In each row I have delete button with unique ID. All I want is when I press delete button jQuery modal window appears and asks me if I really want to delete this row. With two buttons Yes/Cancel. I know how to achieve this with simple onlclick javascript confirm call, but I have no idea how to do this with jQuery. At the moment I have script like this:

Form delete button:

```
<a href="" class='tooltip'>
   <input type='submit' class='btnDel' name='delete' value='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>' />
   <span>Delete Row</span>
</a>
```

Opening dialog div:

```
<div id='dialog-message' title='Delete SOP?'>Do you really want to delete this SOP?</div>
```

And jQuery code which I found on the web:

```
$('.tooltip > .btnDel').click(function(e) {
    $('#dialog-message').dialog('open');
    return false;
  });

  $('#dialog-message').dialog({
    resizable: false,
    autoOpen: false,
    height:140,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Yes": function() {
            $('#inputForm').submit(); //Now submit the form
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
  });
```

With Cancel part everything is ok, but Yes button doesn't work. I don't understand how to submit form with that delete button with unique id what is needed for `$_POST` to use in mysql query later.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a hidden input field and give it the specific data. This could be done in die click-Event.

```
$('#hidden').val($(this).attr('data-id'));
```

would be a variant where you have to set the attribute data-id first.